# Adding text to a cell in table in footer in word document

Tags: powershell, ms-word

Looking for help in adding text to a cell in a table in the footer section of a word document. I have tried the below to just get information/locate the table however have not been successful

```
$objWord.Visible = $false
$objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open($item.FullName,$true)

$objSelection = $objWord.Selection

$Section = $objDoc.Sections.Item(1)
$footer = $Section.Footers.Item(1)
$LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1)
$LETableCols = $LETable.Columns.Count
$LETableRows = $LETable.Rows.Count
write-host $LETable
Write-output "Starting to write... "

for($r=1; $r -le $LETableRows; $r++) {
for($c=1; $c -le $LETableCols; $c++) {
Write-host $r "x" $c
$content = $LETable.Cell($r,$c).Range.Text
Write-host $content
}
}
Write-Host $footer.Tables.count\`
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: If you're able to change the original document it might be easier to manually add a Bookmark into it, then search for that with ```objDoc.Bookmarks("myBookmark")``` and update the contents of  its ```Range``` property with your text. The advantage is that if the document structure changes you don't need to update your code to find the new location in the object hierarchy as long as the Bookmark exists. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmarks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.bookmark.range

Comment: Can't test this now, but there are three possible types of footer with index 1,2,3 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdheaderfooterindex) - you will need to specify the correct one or iterate. Then , instead of $LETable = $objDocument.Tables.Item(1) you will need something like $LETable = $footer.Range.Tables.Item(1)